# How many ports opened by a single application

Tags: networking, nodejs, wireshark

I am writing a program in nodejs that will be firing number of calls to an api. I need to limit number of requests to 100 at a time. I have finished writing the application, but how can I check in Ubuntu how many ports are opened by a single application?

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
sudo netstat -plunt
```

for the full list of active connections, then you can filter for `node` with `grep`  e.g.

```
sudo netstat -plunt | grep node
```

#### Explanation

from `man netstat`

> netstat - Print network connections, routing tables, interface statistics, masquerade connections, and multicast memberships

- -p, --program
     Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.
- -l, --listening
     Show only listening sockets.
- -u UDP
- -n numeric - instead of names, like ssh, http
- -t TCP

Comment: I tried | grep node, but that doesn't seem to be on the list. Any ideas why?